# Laravel Destroy Option not deleting

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

Why do this occurs? This is my index lists of all accounts. I want to just delete a specific category by that category.destroy route but it's

index.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.master')
@section('title','All Categories')
@section('contents')
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-4 col-md-offset-2">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">All Categories</div> 
            <div class="panel-body">
                <article>
                    <div class="table-responsive-vertical shadow-z-1">
                        <!-- Table starts here -->
                        <table id="table" class="table table-hover table-mc-light-blue">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>ID No</th>
                                    <th>Category</th>
                                    <th>Edit/Delete</th>
                                    <th>Status</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            @foreach($categories as $category)
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td data-title="ID">{{$category->id}}</td>
                                    <td data-title="Name">{{$category->name}}</td>
                                    <td><a href="{{ route('category.edit',$category->id)  }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm pull-left">Edit</a>
                                        &nbsp<a href="{{ route('category.destroy', $category->id)  }}" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</a>
                                    </td>

                                </tr>         
                            </tbody>
                            @endforeach
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </article>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
@section('js') 
{!!Html::script('assets/js/jquery.min.js')!!} 
{!!Html::script('assets/js/bootstrap.min.js') !!}
<script>
    $('#flash-overlay-modal').modal();
</script>

<script>
    $('div.alert').not('.alert-important').delay(3000).fadeOut(350);
</script>
@endsection
```

CategoryController.php

```
public function destroy($id){
        $category = Category::findOrFail($id);
        $category->delete();
        Session::flash('flash_message', 'Task successfully deleted!');
        return redirect()->route('category.index');
    }
```

instead it just displays the view specific entry of the category. It's not deleting or something

Comment: If you do a link to the route, then you are actually not accessing that route, because the destroy route is not a `GET`, it's a `DELETE`, therefore you actually should create a small form to the destroy route and use a button to trigger the form action to the actual route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this route:

```
Route::get('category/{category}/destroy',[
  'uses'=>'CategoryController@destroy',
  'as' => 'category.destroy'
]);
```

Comment: @A.Sand While this may work, GET requests should be though of as "read only". You probably don't want to start allowing GET requests to modify data. You'd be better off accessing the proper DELETE route that is created by the resource definition.

Comment: @patricus Yeah it's not secure, but if he protect his requests by authentication, like an admin user, is the same vulnerability?

Comment: @maudev If the links are behind authentication, you don't need to worry about web crawlers, but an auth wall won't prevent other issues like pre-fetching or CSRF attacks (Laravel protects "write" verbs (POST, DELETE, etc) with a token by default; extra work required to guard specific GET requests).

Comment: @patricus Thank u for the info, i'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 2):

To access your destroy route, you have to use the DELETE HTTP request verb. HTML links only allow GET requests.

You should either change your HTML link to an HTML form that [spoofs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing#form-method-spoofing) the DELETE method, or look into using something like [restfulizer.js](https://gist.github.com/fredyounan/8274111) that will automatically convert your delete links to delete forms.

As has been suggested, you could also create a GET route for the delete functionality, but there are potential consequences to this. GET and HEAD requests should generally be thought of as "read only" requests, and should not modify any data. POST, PUT, PATCH, and DELETE requests are generally thought of as "write" requests. A web spider may crawl your delete links and end up deleting all your data, or a web browser may pre-fetch all the GET requests on a page, so the delete link is accessed even though no one clicked the delete button. There are a lot of potential nasty things that can happen when you start allowing GET requests to modify data. There is some good information in [this answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/188860/why-shouldnt-a-get-request-change-data-on-the-server).